# ¿Cómo creo una columna en un DataFrame dependiendo del valor de otras dos columnas?

Tags: python, pandas

Tengo el siguiente DataFrame con Pandas:

```
datos = pd.DataFrame({'Loc': ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'], 
                  'eventAccel': ['0', '0', '1', '2'],
                  'eventBrake': ['2', '0', '0', '1']}
                   )
```

Quiero crear una nueva columna llamada "eventType" que sea:
0 si eventAccel = 0 y eventBrake = 0
1 si eventAccel > 0 y eventBrake = 0
2 si eventAccel = 0 y eventBrake > 0
3 si eventAccel > 0 y eventBrake > 0

Answer (score 4):

Primero, si el tipo de ambas columnas no es `integer` debes hacer el casting primero para que la comparación sea apropiada y eficiente. Partiendo de dos columnas de tipo `int`, puedes usar `pandas.DataFrame.apply` y una función Python que en base a condicionales retorne el valor adecuado:

```
import pandas as pd



datos = pd.DataFrame({'Loc': ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'], 
                      'eventAccel': ['0', '0', '1', '2'],
                      'eventBrake': ['2', '0', '0', '1']},
                      dtype=int
                     )

def categorizar(fila):
    eventAccel = fila.eventAccel
    eventBrake = fila.eventBrake
    if eventAccel == 0:
        if eventBrake == 0:
            return 0
        elif eventBrake > 0:
            return 2

    elif eventAccel > 0:
        if eventBrake == 0:
            return 1
        elif eventBrake > 0:
            return 3

    return -1 # ¿Si ninguna se cumple que hacemos?


datos["Categoría"] = datos.apply(categorizar, axis=1)
```

Aunque flexible, las llamadas a funciones Python repercuten considerablemente en el rendimiento. Si quieres optimizar para mejorar el tiempo de ejecución notablemente se puede vectorizar usando NumPy:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd



datos = pd.DataFrame({'Loc': ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'], 
                      'eventAccel': ['0', '0', '1', '2'],
                      'eventBrake': ['2', '0', '0', '1']},
                      dtype=int
                     )

condiciones = [(datos.eventAccel == 0) & (datos.eventBrake == 0),
               (datos.eventAccel > 0) & (datos.eventBrake == 0),
               (datos.eventAccel == 0) & (datos.eventBrake > 0),
               (datos.eventAccel > 0) & (datos.eventBrake > 0)
               ]
elecciones = np.array((0, 1, 2, 3), dtype="int8")
datos["Categoría"] = np.select(condiciones, elecciones, -1)
```

Para un DataFrame de 10000 filas tenemos:

> **pandas.DataFrame.apply y función Python**: 1.5267951488494873 segundos
>   **numpy.select y máscaras booleanas**:             0.0054912567138671 segundos

Se debe proporcionar un valor para el caso en el que ninguna condición se cumple (si se puede dar este caso). En este caso se usa -1 para preservar el tipo. Si se quiere usar `NaN` (`np.nan`) no hay problema, pera lo columna debe ser de tipo `float`, por ahora Pandas no soporta `NaN` en columnas de tipo entero, aunque esto va a cambiar pronto (característica en beta actualmente).

Comment: ¡Muchas gracias, funciona muy bien!

Answer (score 0):

En caso de ser util par alguien a mi me sirvio esta simple linea de codigo con Numpy.

XY['Nueva Columna'] = np.where(XY['La columna que quiero filtrar'] > 4, '1','0')

0 y 1 son las dos valores que quiero como nuevos en mi nueva preciosa columna.