# dataframe assign() con varios condicionantes

Tags: python, dataframe

Intento asignar valores a una nueva columna según el valor que tengo en otra.

Lo intento así:

```
df.assign(segment = lambda df: df['tier3'].map(lambda tier3: "> 2500" if "_0" in tier3 else "No encontrado"))
```

Si necesito poner más condiciones como puedo hacerlo? Si tier 3 es mayor que 100 quiere meter otro valor, si es mayor que 500 otro, así con todas las condiciones que yo quiera.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Qué es una lambda

A veces tenemos funciones muy sencillas, que no contienen código de control (ni `if`, ni bucles) sino que se componen de una sola sentencia `return` con una expresión que calcula el valor retornado. Por ejemplo:

```
def funcion_simple(x):
    return x**2 +1
```

Este tipo de funciones simples se pueden escribir usando `lambda`, por ejemplo así:

```
funcion_simple = lambda x: x**2+1
```

Cualquiera de las dos definiciones anteriores se invocaría igual (ej: `funcion_simple(3)` y devolvería el mismo resultado (10 en este caso)

La expresión puede ser más complicada, e incluso puede ser una *expresión condicional* como es tu caso:

```
def par_o_impar(dato):
   return "impar" if dato % 2 else "par"
```

Pero observa que sigue siendo un mero `return` con una expresión, y por tanto también puede escribirse como lambda:

```
par_o_impar = lambda dato: "impar" if dato % 2 else "par"
```

No es lo mismo que tener esto otro (aunque el resultado sea el mismo):

```
def par_o_impar(dato):
   if dato%2:
      return "impar"
   else:
      return "par"
```

pues en este caso tenemos dentro de la función estructuras de control, varios `return`, etc. lo que hace que no pueda ser escrito como `lambda`.

## Para qué se usan

Los ejemplos anteriores no son casos típicos de uso de lambdas. No es habitual definir una lambda para asignarla a una variable (que por tanto sería una función). Para eso podríamos haber usado `def` que es más claro.

Las lambda típicamente se usan para pasarlas como parámetros a funciones que esperan una función como parámetro, y para los casos en los que la función a pasar es tan simple que pueda ser escrita como lambda. De ese modo nos evitamos el definir otra función "afuera" y tener que inventar un nombre para ellas, pues las lambda son "funciones anónimas".

El problema es que si lo que queremos hacer dentro de la lambda se complica (requiere bucles, condiciones anidadas, etc) puede no ser posible expresarlo mediante una expresión de una sola línea, y en ese caso ya no podremos hacerlo mediante una lambda.

Pero no pasa nada, siempre se puede escribir una función "normal", todo lo complicada que se quiera, y pasar el nombre de esa función en lugar de la lambda.

## Solución

Por tanto en tu caso puedes hacer algo como:

```
def casos(tier3):
  tier3 = int(tier3)  # Por si llega como cadena
  if 0 < tier3 <=100:
     return "<= 100"
  elif 100 < tier3 <= 500:
     return "> 100"
  elif 500 < tier3 <= 2500:
     return "> 500"
  else:
     return "> 2500"

df.assign(segment = lambda df: df['tier3'].map(casos))
```

> **Nota** Realmente este caso se puede manejar también con una lambda, ya que las expresiones condicionales pueden anidarse:
>
> ```
> lambda t: "<= 100" if 0 < t <= 100 else "> 100" if 100 <t <= 500 else "> 500" if 500 < t <= 2500 else "> 2500"
> ```
>
> pero la legibilidad empeora mucho por lo que personalmente recomendaría la solución dada, con una función con nombre, "externa".

Answer (score 0):

Si no necesitas hacerlo estrictamente con `assign`, puedes usar `numpy` como dice FJSevilla en esta
[respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/193267/c%C3%B3mo-creo-una-columna-en-un-dataframe-dependiendo-del-valor-de-otras-dos-column).

En tu código debería ser algo así:

```
df["segment"] = np.select(
    [df.tier3 < 100, df.tier3 < 500, df.tier3 < 1000, df.tier3 < 1500],  # Condiciones
    ['< 100', '< 500', '< 1000', '< 1500'],  # Valores resultantes
    'no encontrado')  # Salida si no se cumple ninguna condición
```