# Añadir nueva columna con valor dependiente en un dataframe en Python

Tags: python, pandas, condiciones, dataframe, pycharm

Hola soy nueva en Python y estoy intentando hace lo siguiente:

Teniendo un dataframe con valores de notas  (`TheValue`) y con fechas (`Date`), prentendo ordenar el DataFrame por fecha y luego añadir una columna extra en la que ponga por escrito si es suspendido (nota menor que 5), aprobado (mayor o igual que 5 y menor que 9) o sobresaliente (mayor o igual que 9).

Lo de ordenar por fechas lo he conseguido. Pero no consigo asignar los valores a (`Result`) dependiendo del valor de la columna (`TheValue`).
¿Cómo podría crear la columna nueva y al mismo tiempo asignar los valores con un `if...else` multiple?

```
import pandas
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame( {'TheValue':['4','6','9','7'] , 'Date': 
['02/20/2019','01/15/2019','08/21/2019','02/02/2019']})
df['Date']=pd.to_datetime(df.Date)
df.sort_values(by='Date')

df['Result']="Pass"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes usar el método `.apply()` así:

```
df["Results"] = df.apply(lambda x: "Pass" if int(x["TheValue"]) > 5 else "Fail", axis=1)
print(df)

  TheValue       Date Results
0        4 2019-02-20    Fail
1        6 2019-01-15    Pass
2        9 2019-08-21    Pass
3        7 2019-02-02    Pass
```

El método `apply` recibe una función como parámetro, la cual la aplica por cada columna o fila (usando `axis=1`). En este caso he usado una función lambda con *list comprehensions*. De una forma más tradicional, sería lo mismo que:

```
def pass_or_fail(row):
    result = "Fail"
    if int(row["TheValue"]) > 5:
        result = "Pass"
    return result

df["Results"] = df.apply(pass_or_fail, axis=1)
print(df)
  TheValue       Date Results
0        4 2019-02-20    Fail
1        6 2019-01-15    Pass
2        9 2019-08-21    Pass
3        7 2019-02-02    Pass
```

Answer (score 1):

Puedes crear una función en la que incluyes el comportamiento esperado y la aplicas con `apply`, como dice FJSevilla [aquí](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/193267/c%C3%B3mo-creo-una-columna-en-un-dataframe-dependiendo-del-valor-de-otras-dos-column):

En tu caso:

```
import pandas
import pandas as pd


def notas(nota):
    nota = int(nota.TheValue)
    if nota < 5:
        return 'Suspenso'
    elif nota < 9:
        return 'Aprobado'
    else:
        return 'Sobresaliente'


df = pd.DataFrame({'TheValue': ['4', '6', '9', '7'], 'Date':
                   ['02/20/2019', '01/15/2019', '08/21/2019', '02/02/2019']})
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df.Date)
df['Result'] = df.apply(notas, axis=1)
dfsort = df.sort_values(by='Date')
print(dfsort)
```

Esto devolvería:

```
  TheValue       Date         Result
1        6 2019-01-15       Aprobado
3        7 2019-02-02       Aprobado
0        4 2019-02-20       Suspenso
2        9 2019-08-21  Sobresaliente
```

Answer (score 0):

A mi me sirvio esta simple linea de código con Numpy.

XY['Nueva Columna'] = np.where(XY['La columna que quiero filtrar'] > 4, '1','0')

0 y 1 son las dos valores que quiero como nuevos en mi nueva preciosa columna.

saludos